# CSS: How to make stop div from shrinking in height when content change

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am implementing a tab layout in React. I have a `tabs` div which contain two more divs `tab-headers` and `tab-container`. The `tab-container` div contains individual `tabs` divs. The content in the `tabs` div vary in height and it always shrinks to fit the content. How ever I want the div to be the size of the largest `tabs` div. I do not want to use static heights.

This is the css:

```
.tab-headers{
    display: grid;
    grid-auto-flow: column;
    width: fit-content;
}

.tab-header {
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 5px;
    background: var(--primary-bg);
    padding: 5px 20px;
}

.tabs-container {
    padding: 10px;
}

.tabs{
    height: 100%;
    background-color: var(--active-bg);
}

.tab{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: none;
}

.active {
    display: initial;
}

.active-header {
    background-color: var(--active-bg);
    border-top: 2px solid var(--accent-bg);
}

.tab-header:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

This is what's happening:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `min-height` and `max-height` properties in your CSS and set `overflow` to `scroll` if needed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but is their any way to set the min-height to the height of the tallest child of the div

Comment: No. That is just not possible with CSS alone. You'll need to write the javascript to get the height of maxed tab and then set it dynamically to all others. A better solution for you would be to predetermine the height of the tab to the highest tab and set it to that. And, in runtime, fetch the height and update it if needed.

Comment: You always will know the actual height of the tab beforehand if you designed it properly for each resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `min-height` in your css.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but is their any way to set the min-height to the height of the tallest child of the div